# VB.NET open source ORM (Like Doctrine for PHP)

Tags: php, vb.net, orm

What is the most doctrine-like ORM for VB.NET? With good documentation.

What are the most popular object relational mappers (ORMs) for VB.NET which is like Doctrine (PHP) and have a good extensive documentation?

NHibernate seems to be the main one.

Comment: take a look http://www.ORMBattle.net

Answer (score 1):

look at Luna, an opensource ORM for vb.net

http://www.diegolunadei.it/luna